# Macro defined C typedef

Tags: c, embedded, xc8

I have a bit of a copy/paste issue here.
I have some datatypes that I'm typedefing based on the number of bits I need.  I'm using an 8-bit MCU, so using the smallest type that the data fits in matters.

The code ends up looking something like this:

```
#ifndef INT24_MAX 
// For portability
typedef int32_t int24_t
#define int24_t int24_t
#endif

#if MY_BITS <= 8
typedef int8_t MY_TYPE_T;
#warning MY_TYPE_T is int8_t

#elif MY_BITS <= 16
typedef int16_t MY_TYPE_T;
#warning MY_TYPE_T is int16_t

#elif MY_BITS <= 24
typedef int24_t MY_TYPE_T;
#warning MY_TYPE_T is int24_t

#elif MY_BITS <= 32
typedef int32_t MY_TYPE_T;
#warning MY_TYPE_T is int32_t

#else
#error MY_TYPE_T is too big.
#endif
```

I don't like these lines:

```
typedef int16_t MY_TYPE_T;
#warning MY_TYPE_T is int16_t
```

Because int16_t and MY_TYPE_T are copy pasted.  Also, since I am using this over multiple variables, there's a copy/paste issue there since I repeat the same code fore MY_TYPE_2_T and MY_TYPE_3_t (note: not actually naming these "MY_TYPE" in the project).

I'm looking for a way to typedef a type based on the number of bits and output a message about the type or give an error if the type gets too big.

```
//Something like this
#define MY_BITS (10 + 2)
Int_BestFit(MY_TYPE_N, MY_BITS);
```

Comment: what is "copy/paste issue" ?

Comment: Learn about the differences between the preprocessor and the actual compiler. `#ifndef int24_t ` will not work for obvious reasons. And 8 bit MCUs typically don't have a `int24_t`. This is only avaliable on 24 bit platforms. Your text smells like an XY problem. Reason for using fixed width types is to have the trypes you actually **need*. Also you must not `typedef` these names yourself in your application code.

Comment: @EugeneSh.What I mean is that the code is not "DRY."  http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself.  I have copied the above code multiple times to typedef multiple types.  It's a code smell https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell.

Comment: @olaf Respectfully, I think your comment is incorrect.  The ifndef works on gcc c99, and on xc8.  int24_t is defined in xc8: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002053F.pdf#page=151.  However int24_t is not in gcc, which I use to test my code.  I agree the code smells, hence the question.  This is why I am using fixed widths.  The precise application is I have a 8,10, or 12-bit ADC value, that I want to treat as signed (+1 bit) and decimate over n samples (+ log2(n) bits), left shift (+m bits) and then filter using a FIR.

Comment: @RyanB: Please read the standard! 7.20.1.1 is very clear about that `intN_t` are **typedefs*. `#define` only works with macros from obvious reasons. Also the standard is clear about the names are reserved and shall not be defined in any means by application code. If that is about your ADC value, use the type most appropriate (which might be `int`) and leave optimisations to the compiler unless it proves to cause problems in the final firmware. Note that shifting signed integers in C is also problematic. Specific values/shifts can cause undefined behaviour or are implementation defined.

Comment: @Olaf `int24_t` is not part of the [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf#page=268).  It is however an extension added in XC compilers.  It's perfectly fine to define my own types that are outside the standard.  The ADC API returns an `uint16_t`, which I shift, and then assign to a signed var.  Shifting unsigned int is defined and perfectly fine.  The reason why I shift by 2 instead of multiply by 4 is that XC8 does not currently optimize a multiply by constant to a shift operation.  It instead calls the builtin int multiply.

Comment: @RyanB: Please read the standard as I asked you multiple times. The standard does not restrict to the doubling width types (see 7.31.10, too). Any type with that name is subject to be provided by the implementation. First you should learn in C is to differentiate between madattory features and optional features by the standard and compiler extensions. The XC8 compiler is know to be buggy and badly optimising. Maybe you want to evaluate an alternative, too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117640/discussion-between-ryan-b-and-olaf).

Comment: Does your compiler support `int_least` definitions? If so, can you do something like `#define INT_LEAST(BITS) int_least##BITS##_t` ?